# cant use external js with angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im trying to import the [twitter-bootstrap-wizard](https://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard) javascript library to my `angular 2` project but always getting this error:

> **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_jquery**(...).bootstrapWizard is not a function

I just create a new angualr app using the `angular-cli 1.0.0` then add the scripts in the index.html like:

```
  <body>
     <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/1.2/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Then in my component:

```
//
declare var bootstrapWizard : any;
import * as $ from 'jquery';
//

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    (<any>$('#wizard')).bootstrapWizard()
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you using cdn, just add declare

```
declare const jQuery: any;
```

or you can remove cdn, then install jquery from npm, then use your import

```
npm i --save jquery

import * as $ from 'jquery';
```